# WSS 3.0 fails to hide quick launch items for which the current user does not have access

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, windows-sbs

I'm running a Small Business Server 2008 with Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 (WSS 3.0). I thought WSS was supposed to hide menu items for which the current logged in user don't have access? Apparently, all users can see all links, regardless of whether they have access.

This applies to both links to newly created sub-sites as well as document libraries/lists.

Is this expected behaviour, or is there a misconfiguration somewhere that causes the links to stay visible even for users without access?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this "security trimming" does not happen for links that were manually put into the navigation!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a similar issue.  Part of my problem was that I was editing the quick launch menu directly in Site Settings, instead of selecting whether to display the list in list "Settings/Title, description and navigation."

Items I had displayed on the quick launch by editing it directly (in Site Settings) were displayed for all users.
Items I had displayed on the quick launch using the list settings were security trimmed.

Not sure whether this applies to you; kind of a weird one.

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have created unique permissions for the sub sites and lists, yes the users DO have permissions and access to those newly created items. By default, items inherit permission settings from the parent.

Comment: Thanks SharePointAdminGuy! I have definitely created unique permissions on the subsite. I have given explicit permissions only to certain people, while the links are visible by everyone. When people without access clicks the link, however, they get an 'Access denied' message (which is expected behavior).